# Loud ticking noise from engine that increases when idling, but disappears entirely when accelerating

Tags: engine, noise, land-rover

I have a 2008 Land Rover with a TD4 engine and 90000 miles. The engine’s been making a ticking noise while idling that gets louder if the car continues to idle, but when I speed up, it completely disappears. I’ve recently changed the oil, and the water is full. I can’t find any other issues like this on the internet. Am at a loss.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Was it making the noise prior to the oil change? Are you sure you have enough oil in it?

Comment: Yes, the oil was changed because of the noise. And I have checked to make sure the amount is enough.